# How to get the path of maven dependency jar files in Java?

Tags: java, maven

In my application I'm using a dynamic java compiler. To let the dynamic compiler to know the build path I could do:

```
List<String> optionList = new ArrayList<String>();
optionList.addAll(Arrays.asList("-classpath", System.getProperty("java.class.path")));
```

But there was still "ClassNotFoundException" in compiling, because the path of the maven dependencies are not added to the "**optionList**". How can I get the path to the .jar files? E.g. "C:\Users\myUserName\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.2\javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar"